# React Storybook blank page when run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I am trying to load the demo storybook stories.
I created a react app using `create-react-app` and run `npm start`. It starts on port: 3000.
Then when I run `npm run storybook`, it opens a browser on port:6006. But displays a blank page only.

Comment: It is rather difficult to help if you provide next to nothing in the way of details. Are there any errors logged in the console? Can you provide your package.json file?

Comment: there are no errors. It just displays a blank page in the browser. and not the demo storybook stories

Comment: I think there are some errors , open the developer console , I have same problem and it has some problem with React Hooks ,

Answer (score 5):

What helped me was to run

```
rm yarn.lock
yarn install
```

after installing storybook into my project

Answer (score 2):

Apparently react has upgraded to version 17.0.0, but storybook hasn't made the switch yet.
If you take version 16.14.0 of react it should work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjb_QcQhRrs

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna stay on react version 17 then you could upgrade storybook to  prelease by doing

```
npx sb@next upgrade --prerelease
```

for additional information please refer GitHub issue [#12408](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12408)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your browser cache. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`npm ci` saved the day for me and fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

My problem was because I updated `@storybook/preset-create-react-app` too and it seems I shouldn't have.

When `@storybook/preset-create-react-app` was reverted back to initial version `3.2.0` in my case, and `@storybook/react` updated to latest ^6.5.4 - everything was fine.